# How to natively add an image to a button in C++ WinAPI (without MFC)?

Tags: c++, winapi, mingw, codeblocks, windows-7-x64

Okay, I want to add an image to a button **ALONG WITH TEXT** without making the button in my RC file. Is this even possible, or do I **NEED** to use an RC file to make the button in able to put an image in it? My image is `#define`d in "resource.h" and the image is declared in "resources.rc". Both "main.cpp" and "resources.rc" include the "resource.h" header. I really don't want to make a button using resources, but if it
s the only way to make a button with an image **AND** text, then I'll do it. All I need to know is how to put an image into a button in WinAPI.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298354(v=vs.85).aspx here you can find how to create it

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775951(v=vs.85).aspx here is the style that you have to set, look at BS_BITMAP, BS_IMAGE

Comment: Since no one bothered asking, I will. Have you considered an owner-draw button implementation? They're honestly not that hard to do. Search the world for BS_OWNERDRAW implementations for samples Oh, and if you do this, be *sure* to follow the windows ui guidelines on color usage (for highlights, shadows, etc) and system-colo-scheme change detection. you would probably not be surprised b how many people completely skip that when doing owner-draw UI elements.

Comment: Okay, I've narrowed this all down for Code::Blocks. I need to use `LoadImage()`, and then print the image into the button using `SendDlgItemMessage()`. Is this correct? If so, can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

1. Add manifest file to your application, manifest file should be named `YourApp.exe.manifest`
2. Add this into your manifest file(more on manifest file here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773175%28VS.85%29.aspx):

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
   <assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
   <assemblyIdentity
       version="1.0.0.0"
       processorArchitecture="*"
       name="CompanyName.ProductName.YourApplication"
       type="win32"
   />
   <description>Your application description here.</description>
   <dependency>
       <dependentAssembly>
           <assemblyIdentity
               type="win32"
               name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
               version="6.0.0.0"
               processorArchitecture="*"
               publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
               language="*"
           />
       </dependentAssembly>
   </dependency>
   </assembly>
   ```
3. Link your application with `ComCtl32.lib`
4. Add the manifest to your application resource file `CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID RT_MANIFEST "YourApp.exe.manifest"`
5. Call `InitCommonControls()` at the beginning of WinMain

**END UPDATE**

1. example code for button creation(IMAGE + TEXT), memory leak prone because of LoadBitmap:

   ```
   HWND hwnd_button = CreateWindowEx(
           0,
           "BUTTON", //ascii
           "Button text",
           WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_PUSHBUTTON,
           10, 
           145,
           50,
           50,
           hwnd_parent,
           NULL,
           //GetModuleHandle(NULL)
           (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd_parent, GWL_HINSTANCE),
           NULL);

   SendMessage((HWND) m_hWndButton,
           (UINT) BM_SETIMAGE,
           (WPARAM) IMAGE_BITMAP,
           (LPARAM) LoadBitmap(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1)));
   ```

Comment: `||In function 'LRESULT WinProc(HWND__*, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)':| |94|error: cannot convert 'const wchar_t*' to 'const CHAR*' for argument '2' to 'HWND__* CreateWindowExA(DWORD, const CHAR*, const CHAR*, DWORD, int, int, int, int, HWND__*, HMENU__*, HINSTANCE__*, void*)'| ||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|`                                                                                                                                    Line 94 is after the `(HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),)`:                                                                `NULL);`

Comment: Remove L literal sign before strings "BUTTON" and "Button text" or push your project into Unicode environment :-)

Comment: delete L if you do not have a unicode enabled project, wait 2 min as now i have access to a compiler

Comment: Okay, when I remove the XP mainfest, the text shows up, but the icon doesn't. Suggestions?

Comment: And right now I'm on XP, but when later tonight I'll be on Win7 64-Bit. So I read that BM_SETIMAGE has no effect on XP when without the BS_ICON flag? Correct or wrong?

Comment: On Xp, yes, it has no effect.

Comment: So if I run my code (that the button doesn't show up on) on my Win7 64-Bit laptop, it will work?

Comment: @Mike, try also on XP with this code, according to the documentation it should work. Please share us the result... thanks.

Comment: Well, no image in button on Win7 64-Bit. Is it even possible to have an image in a button in WinAPI?

Comment: @mike, It works, I have tested the code on windows 7 64bit. If you want I can send the complete test application...

Comment: Yes please do so. I don't know what's wrong though. Do you use pastebin? I'm up for that if you would prefer to use pastebin. If not then I'm still okay, as long as I learn how to make in image in a button along with the button text.

Comment: How exactly do I import that into Code::Blocks 10.05? It gave a **HUGE** list of errors and warnings when I made a C::B project from the files made from Visual Studio.

Comment: You can understand the code using Visual Studio Express. After you will understand the code, you can port it to Code::Blocks. You can check the value returned by LoadBitmap, probably this is your problem.

Comment: But I don't like Visual Studio. Thank you very much for your help. You've gotten me three steps closer to my final goal :>)

Comment: Okay, I can't even get any PNG/Image external library to work. All I want to do now is load a PNG image onto the WinAPI window. Suggestions for FreeImage/LibPNG?